# Counting continusly with scroll, speed varies

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

My boss asked me to mimic this site:

http://mailchimp.com/2013/#by-the-numbers

I've been able to figure out every piece except for the white numbers. The really cool (but tricky) effect is that the speed of the count accelerates/decelerates depending on the data-count attribute, even though the distance between sections is the same.

It looks like they used waypoints.js to differentiate between sections. I searched for a plug-in that would adjust speed depending on the data inputs, but I could only find ones like countTo.js which trigger then count, rather than continuously count up and down as the user scrolls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This intrigued me, so I gave it a shot.

As far as I know, waypoints.js only fires when an element hits the edge of the viewport. I don't think you could use it for this kind of thing, because you need to continually update your counter. So I wrote this without any jQuery plugin.

Disclaimer: This code may or may not work for you, either way, please regard it as nothing more than a sketch of a solution, it still needs to be improved in several places to be used for a production site.

```js
var current = $('.step').first();

$('.step').each(function() {
  var start = $(this).data('count'),
    end = $(this).next().data('count'),
    height = $(this).height(),
    offset = $(this).offset().top,
    increment = end ? height / (end - start) : 0; //after how many pixels of scrolling do we need to incremwent our counter? Set to 0 for last element, just in case

  // just adding the count as text, so it gets displayed
  $(this).text(start);

  //store increment and offset, we need those in our scrollListener
  $(this).data({
    increment: increment,
    offset: offset
  });
});

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementscrollpos,
    counter;

  //check if scrolled to the next element
  if (current.next().data('offset') < scrollpos) {
    current = current.next();
  } else if (current.data('offset') > scrollpos) {
    current = current.prev();
  }

  //calculate the current counter value;
  elementscrollpos = scrollpos - current.data('offset');
  counter = Math.floor(current.data('count') + elementscrollpos / current.data('increment'));

  $('.counter').text(counter);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.step {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="counter"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="0"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="1"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="2"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="8"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="100"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="110240"></div>
<div class="step" data-count="110250"></div>
```